# I can't determine the number of the elements of $\{(x,y)\}$ such that $ax_i+by_i\leqq ab$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, elementary-number-theory

The given problem is as follows.

$a,b \in \mathbb{P}\setminus{\{2\}} \ \land a\neq b,\ \ x,y\in \mathbb{N}$

Determine the number of the elements of $\{(x,y)\} $ such that $ax_i+by_i\leqq ab$

The answer is $ \ \displaystyle\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2} \ $ but I can't deduce it.

I found the following facts.

$1\leqq x_i\leqq b-1$

$1\leqq y_i\leqq a-1$

$\therefore ax+by\neq ab$

$k:=$The answer.

$1\leqq i\lt j \leqq k \Rightarrow ax_i+by_i\neq ax_j+by_j$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{P} \setminus \{ 2 \}$? Is it the set of all odd numbers?

Comment: No.That is the set of the all odd prime numbers.

Comment: I have a hint : if $ax + by < ab$, then $a(b-x) + b(a-x) > ab$. There is a bijection, notice the divided by $2$ in the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of the lattice points on $ax+by\leq ab,x>0,y>0$.

We have $ax+by\leqq ab\implies 0<x<b,0<y<a$.

Since the number of the lattice points on $ax+by<ab,x>0,y>0$ (the red part) and $ax+by>ab,x<b,y<a$ are the same, and there are no points on $ax+by=ab$ as you point out, we need to simply divide the number of the lattice points on $0<x<b,0<y<a$ by $2$.
Now we have
$$k=\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}$$

[image]

This image is for $(a,b)=(7,11)$